# How to declare DOCTYPE and ENTITY in XML using StAX Parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, doctype, stax

I am using StAX parser for generating XML. Here is what I need to generate:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE FILE PUBLIC "-//SOMETHING//DTD bla bla bla//EN" "scheme.dtd" 
    [
        <!ENTITY file1 SYSTEM "D:\repo\file1.pdf" NDATA application_pdf>
    ]
>

<FILES>
    <FILE>
        <METADATA></METADATA>
        <CONTENT></CONTENT>
..... and so on .....
```

The problem is I don't know how to declare DOCTYPE and ENTITY tags. Tried to google it and didn't find any solutions. Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for this in the XMLStreamWriter class: [writeDTD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeDTD%28java.lang.String%29). Just pass the entire DOCTYPE blob into there.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. I disabled characters escaping in factory:

```
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty("escapeCharacters", false);
```

And wrote DOCTYPE and ENTITY using writeCharacters method:

```
writer.writeCharacters("doctype bla bla");
```